# Use Devise :confirmable without time limit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm using Devise for authentication in my application. I don't want to require email confirmation when a user signs up, but I do want to require it if the user wants the app to send them email updates. Is this possible with the built-in :confirmable feature of Devise? I found the setting to set how long a user can log in without confirming, but I essentially want to set that to "forever".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb. You can probably override `confirmation_period_valid?` by returning always `true`.

Alternatively, maybe you can change your setting to something like `10000.years.from_now`, which might be a good enough estimation for "forever", perhaps?

Comment: Would I do that by just adding that method to my User model?

Comment: Yes, I thought about the `10000.years` solution, but it seemed like I should be able to do something cleaner.

Comment: I think that's way better than monkey patching, and since Devise makes that option available, might as well go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `config/initializers/devise.rb` for

```
  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
  # confirming their account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
  # able to access the website for two days without confirming their account,
  # access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
  # the user cannot access the website without confirming their account.
  # config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days
```

Set it to 1000.years. Then in your `email_updates` method, call [`#confirmed?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable) to test if the user has confirmed their account. If not, send them to the page to re-send the confirmation link, as it will likely have expired by now.